# Django Rest Framework Serializers: exclude from validation related entity

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have m2m related entities:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
       max_length=80,
       blank=False,
       unique=True
)

class File(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    uploader = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        blank=False,
        unique=True,
    )
```

and serializers for them:

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ('id', 'name')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'name': {
                'validators': [],
            },
        }

class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'tags')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        tags_data = validated_data.pop('tags')

        if 'name' in validated_data:
           instance.name = validated_data['name']


        instance_tags = instance.tags.all()
        new_tag_list = []

        # add new tags
        for tag in tags_data:
            tag, created = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tag['name'])
            new_tag_list.append(tag)
            if tag not in instance_tags:
                instance.tags.add(tag)

        # remove old tags
        for instance_tag in instance_tags:
            if instance_tag not in new_tag_list:
                instance.tags.remove(instance_tag)

        return instance
```

as you can see I turned off all validation for Tag.name field in TagSerializer by this code setting: `extra_kwargs = {'name': {'validators': []}}`
This is because of validation errors during saving updated File:

```
serializer = FileSerializer(file, data=request.data, partial=True)
if serializer.is_valid(): 
    ...
```

If you have File with list of tags and just want to add or remove some tags, you'll have error 'tag with such name already exists'.

So this spike is working, but for now I don't have unique check for Tag.name.
I tried to write something like what in FileSerializer:

```
class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = File
       extra_kwargs = {
           'tags': {
                'validators': [],
            },
        }
```

but of course it's not working.
Question is about any possibilities to not validate Tag entities at all when I add/remove its bindings with file.

Comment: please, add full error stack

Comment: there is no error stack DRF automate it and returns 400 error with body: {"tags":[{"name":["tag with this name already exists."]},{"name":["tag with this name already exists."]}]} -- in this exact case File had 3 tags and I tried to delete one, so sent list of two that should left

Comment: by code you show i do not see validation for `TagSerializer`,  please show you apiview.

Comment: again: validation here provided out-of-the box by DRF, just remove extra_kwargs ... from Meta of TagSerializer, and Tag.name will be checked if it's unique, because it's declared as unique=True, in class Tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try, this way for `update`, but if this solution correct for you, you need also override the `create` method.

```
class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    #                                       ^^^^^^

    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'tags')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # Override tags_data = validated_data.pop('tags')
        # this way
        request = self.context['request']
        tags_data = request.data.get('tags', [])

        # Next your current code
```

in serializer initial add [extra-context](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) , when you use [views from drf](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/) 
 context added by `get_serializer` method.

```
serializer = FileSerializer(file, data=request.data, partial=True, context={'request': request})
```

Comment: by default while you use drf, you create api with drf view and context not empty, i updated the answer, you can try

Comment: Now it's working, great! And thank you! So I'll had to use request.data instead of validated_data in both of update and create methods?

Comment: glad to help you, yes you are right need use it in both methods, and you can add method `update_tags` and put tag logic inside it for more readable.

Comment: ok, but, does this mean what for now I'll use raw data from request and I'll need to validate data for another fields in some way?

Comment: no, raw data need only for fields with `read_only=True` property, other data you can and have to get from validate data

Answer (score 0):

You can also get tags from instance, no need to send whole request through context.

```
tags_data = self.initial_data.get('tags', [])
```